# How to extract multiple structures from a string with boost::spirit

Tags: c++, boost-spirit-qi

I have some complicated structures and i want to extract their data from a text using 
boost::spirit library (I've selected this one for efficiency purpose).

but i will ask my question in simpler way.

assume, we have two structures like these:

```
struct person 
{
   std::string name;
   uint8_t age; 
};
```

and

```
struct fruit
{
   std::string color;
   std::double average_weight;
};
```

and our text that included these data is presented below:

"... (jane, 23) (david, 19) (mary, 30) [yello,100] [green, 60.6] [red, 30.5]"

now, the problem is "extracting these data in suitable format"

for example by call handler for each struct or push_back them on vector.

any help would be greatly appreciated!

is there any code sample about that?!

Comment: Isn't [that](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/spirit/example/qi/num_list2.cpp) almost what you need?

Comment: No, this one is based on primitive data type (double). The main problem is "the way to define struct and presenting to parser"

Comment: Oh, sorry. Then you need to use [semantic actions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/semantic_actions.html)! I don't really have compiler near at hand and therefore can post working example only tomorrow, but I strongly recommend you to look at the documentation and [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/spirit/example/qi/complex_number.cpp) particular example and answer your own question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**call handlers for parsed structures.**

```
#include <string>

#define BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_DECLTYPE

#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/qi.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;
namespace phoenix = boost::phoenix;
namespace fusion = boost::fusion;

struct person
{
    std::string name;
    uint8_t age;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT
(
    person,
    (std::string, name)
    (uint8_t, age)
);

struct fruit
{
    std::string color;
    double average_weight;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT
(
    fruit,
    (std::string, color)
    (double, average_weight)
);


template <typename _Iterator>
struct parser : 
    qi::grammar<_Iterator, void(), ascii::space_type>
{
    parser() :
        parser::base_type(main)
    {
        main = 
            *(
                _person[ ([](const person &person_)
                        { 
                            // Add handler here
                        }) ]
                | _fruit[ ([](const fruit &fruit_)
                        { 
                            // Add handler here
                        }) ]

            );

        _person = qi::lit('(') >> *(qi::char_ - ',') >> ',' >> qi::ushort_ >> ')';
        _fruit = qi::lit('[') >> *(qi::char_ - ',') >> ',' >> qi::double_ >> ']';
    }

    qi::rule<_Iterator, void(), ascii::space_type> main;
    qi::rule<_Iterator, person(), ascii::space_type> _person;
    qi::rule<_Iterator, fruit(), ascii::space_type> _fruit;
};


int main()
{
    typedef std::string::const_iterator iterator;

    std::string input_ = "(jane, 23000) (david, 19) (mary, 30) [yello,100] [green, 60.6] [red, 30.5]";

    iterator iterator_ = std::begin(input_);

    bool result_ = qi::phrase_parse(iterator_, iterator(std::end(input_)),  parser<iterator>(), ascii::space)
        && iterator_ == std::end(input_);

    return 0;
}
```

P.S. Not all compiler can build that code because of lambdas in semantic actions. (msvs don't) In this case you have to use something else (phoenix::bind for example)

**store parsed structures in a vector**

```
typedef boost::variant <
    person,
    fruit
> variant;

template <typename _Iterator>
struct parser : 
    qi::grammar<_Iterator, std::vector < variant > (), ascii::space_type>
{
    parser() :
        parser::base_type(main)
    {
        main = *(_person | _fruit);

        _person = qi::lit('(') >> *(qi::char_ - ',') >> ',' >> qi::ushort_ >> ')';
        _fruit = qi::lit('[') >> *(qi::char_ - ',') >> ',' >> qi::double_ >> ']';
    }

    qi::rule<_Iterator, std::vector < variant > (), ascii::space_type> main;
    qi::rule<_Iterator, person(), ascii::space_type> _person;
    qi::rule<_Iterator, fruit(), ascii::space_type> _fruit;
};
```